# Xcode change repositories

Tags: ios, xcode

Maybe anyone knows a way how to change repositories.

I have to continue a project made by other company, and they have their svn repository in their server. I'v created my own git repository, yet the files keep commiting to the old svn. Deleting the first repository in organizer does not help at all, if i try to commit file, it recreates...

So how do I switch between old svn to my new git repository ?

Comment: Yay! A question tagged "xcode" that's actually about Xcode, and not Cocoa-Touch programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

close XCode, go into the terminal and delete all the .svn directories from the folder hierarchy, issue "git init ." in the root directory and now restart XCode.

Comment: How can I find .svn directories in my project through the console?

Comment: find . -name ".svn" -type d -exec rm -rf {} \; -prune -print